# Hide Gmail Labels on iPhone app

Tags: ios, gmail

I have the Gmail on my iPhone and iPad, both running the latest version or iOS and the Gmail app. In the app, is there any way to get rid of/hide the 'important' and 'all mail'. When I toggle the sidebar in the app, both those labels appear under the 'more' category. Everything I've tried so far hasn't worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you login to  Gmail (not the mobile site) via the browser, you can go to:

- Settings (the wheel right on top)
- Filters
- Uncheck the `Show in IMAP`
- after a short time the folders will be invisible in the mail apps.

Comment: This hides them from MobileMail but not the Gmail app

Comment: That's a google fail!

Answer (score 2):

#### Currently, **this is not possible**.

You can send feedback to Google through the app: gear icon → Help and Feedback….